# F# idiomatic conversion of async while loop accumulation

Tags: f#, azure-cosmosdb, idioms

What is the idiomatic F# way of handling an asynchronous while loop accumulation?

I'm working with the new (still in preview) Azure Cosmos DB SDK. Querying the database returns a `CosmosResultSetIterator<T>` which has a `HasMoreResults` property and a `FetchNextSetAsync()` method. My straight-up translation of the C# code looks like this:

```f#
let private fetchItemsFromResultSet (resultSetIterator: CosmosResultSetIterator<'a>) =
    let results = ResizeArray<'a>()
    async {
        while resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults do
            let! response = resultSetIterator.FetchNextSetAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            results.AddRange(response |> Seq.toArray)

        return Seq.toList results
    }
```

Comment: Minor: I would move `let results` into the async block as I suspect that's what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a look at the [AsyncSeq](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/library/AsyncSeq.html) package.  You can use it to create asynchronously computed sequences and then iterate them asynchronously or in parallel.  This allows for the async-binding to be inside the sequence and the yield to occur asynchronously, so you don't have to build up an accumulator explicitly.

You can use it to do something like:

```
open FSharp.Control

let private fetchItemsFromResultSet (resultSetIterator: CosmosResultSetIterator<'a>) =
    asyncSeq {
        while resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults do
            let! response = resultSetIterator.FetchNextSetAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            yield! response |> AsyncSeq.ofSeq
    }
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, thanks. One question though, in the code above, response itself is a sequence and I need to return each of the items in response, so I don't think yield response will work. I would seem to need some sort of nested yield.

Comment: @BrianVallelunga Oh, that's easy enough.  You just make it a `yield!` and it will flatten the sequence.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it works quite well. I did have to make one small change though since response isn't directly compatible with an `AsyncSeq`. I ended up changing the last line to `yield! response |> AsyncSeq.ofSeq`

Answer (score 3):

Very recently, [FSharp.Control.TaskSeq](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.TaskSeq) was added to support tasks natively with seqs. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384424/1634430) by @[Just another metaprogrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418488/just-another-metaprogrammer) can be rewritten as

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Control.TaskSeq"

open FSharp.Control

let private fetchItemsFromResultSet (resultSetIterator: CosmosResultSetIterator<'a>) = taskSeq {
    while resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults do
        let! response = resultSetIterator.FetchNextSetAsync()
        yield! response |> TaskSeq.ofSeq
}
```

Comment: This also looks great now, thanks.

Comment: I'm the author of said package ;). You can simplify the `yield!` further, it can take any `list`, `array`, `seq`, `AsyncSeq` or `TaskSeq`. That is: `yield! response` does the same (and has one less conversion).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO tail-recursion is preferable to while loops as it's one way to avoid mutation.

For example:

```
let fetchItemsFromResultSet (resultSetIterator: CosmosResultSetIterator<'a>) =
  let rec loop results =
    async {
      if resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults then
        let! vs = resultSetIterator.FetchNextSetAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask
        let vs = vs |> Seq.toList
        return! loop (vs::results)
      else
        // List.rev needed because batches are in reverse
        return results |> List.rev |> List.concat
    }
  loop []
```

Comment: This is the approach I'd take without AsyncSeq.

Comment: This is not tail-recursive, even when it looks like one. See: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12749

Comment: @TuomasHietanen is correct, this will blow up pretty quickly, depending on the depth of your set.